# Bitwise rotation function in c

Tags: python, c

I need to translate a python function to c. All the bitwise operators seem to be the same in c, so I thought I could pretty much just copy the code and add a semicolon. Here is the python code:

```py
def ROTR(x, n, w=32):
    return ((x >> n) | (x << w - n)) & ((1 << w) - 1)
```

This works as it should, running it on the number 5, with a shift of 1 and w=32 yields 2147483650.

Here is my c function:

```c
int ROTR(int x, int n, int w) {
    return ((x >> n) | (x << w - n)) & ((1 << w) - 1);
}
```

This yields 0, with the same parameters.

I tried taking the function apart, but I can't figure out what causes this mistake.

Comment: In C, an `int` is at least 16 bits, so it does not per se have anough bits to store the intermediate results.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How would I fix this? I tried making the ints longs but it still gives the same result.

Comment: bitrot.c:4:27: runtime error: left shift of 5 by 31 places cannot be represented in type 'int'
bitrot.c:4:44: runtime error: shift exponent 32 is too large for 32-bit type 'int'

Comment: Why are you rotating bits in a *signed* integer like this? It has potential for undefined behavior. You should cast to unsigned type first.

Comment: @hyde I am very new to c, so I don't know much about signed and unsigned, what undefined behaviour are we talking about here?

Comment: @b3nj4m1n time to get a good C book then. C is not a language that one gets good at by "experimenting"!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm not trying to get good at it.

Comment: @b3nj4m1n good = able to produce readable code that does not break every time you compile it with different switches.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ok, maybe I am trying to get good at it...

Comment: @b3nj4m1n I suggest you research signed vs unsigned in C. Also read up on undefined behavior in C. UB is a huge pitfall for newcomers and may hinder your progression learning C unnecessarily.

Comment: First of all, bit twiddling in C should probably always be done with **unsigned integers**. Second, there are no arbitrary precision integers in C, so the `w` is probably exaggeration. You would really want to have a different function for each width. Then the 3rd problem is that shifts by exactly the width of the integer are already undefined, so...

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined in C. If you run out of 1 bits when shifting left (so the number changes signedness or loses 0 bits), you hit this. Signed numbers are evil in C if there is chance of overflow and you need to care, because optimizing compilers can be (or become in future compiler versions) innocently devious when they optimize code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, left shifts of `int` and other signed integers are undefined when overflow occurs, and right shifts of negative values are implementation-defined. Therefore, shifting 5 left by `w - n` = 32 − 1 = 31 bits with a 32-bit `int` has undefined behavior.

To avoid this, use an unsigned integer type for shifting. While you can use `unsigned int`, it may be preferable to include `<stdint.h>` and use a type with a specific width, such as `uint32_t`:

```
uint32_t ROTR(uint32_t x, int n, int w)
{
    return x >> n | x << w-n;
}
```

Additionally, shifting by an amount greater than or equal to the width of the left operand is undefined, so `1 << w` is undefined when `w` is 32 and `int` is 32 bits. This attempt at masking with `((1 << w) - 1)` may also be unnecessary; when left operand of a shift and/or the function return type is an unsigned integer type, evaluations will automatically be performed as if masked. (If you want the function to support narrower words than its nominal type, then a mask could be useful. However, you must either construct it carefully to avoid undefined behavior or you must apply it conditionally, not in the case that `w` is the width of the nominal type.)